# Как выполнить ввод сообщения через телеграм бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, telegram

Пытаюсь реализовать программу, которая будет отправлять сообщения с расписанием уроков в течение всего дня. Как я могу реализовать функцию, которая будет спрашивать у пользователя время начала и конца его уроков в течении дня? Нужно как-нибудь дописать в строчках 70 и 74. По сути мне просто нужен аналог input() для телеграм бота. В документации telebot я провел не мало времени...

```
import telebot
from telebot import types


bot = telebot.TeleBot("5367101043:AAFxepYV_WeK77J36ADtcRxZyPQBYbrw8bY")
printy = bot.send_message

how_many_lessons = None
time_lesson = None
time_break = None
days = ["Понедельник", "Вторник", "Среда", "Четверг", "Пятница"]

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def send_welcome(message):
    printy(message.chat.id, f"Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}!")
    printy(message.chat.id, f"Для начала напиши /pop")

@bot.message_handler(commands=["pop"])
def pop(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    settings_schedule = (types.KeyboardButton("Настройка расписание уроков"))
    settings_time = (types.KeyboardButton("Настройка времени проведения уроков"))
    bot_info = (types.KeyboardButton("Информация о боте"))
    markup.add(settings_schedule, settings_time, bot_info)
    printy(message.chat.id, "Возможности бота:", reply_markup=markup)

def settings_schedule(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    change_schedule = (types.KeyboardButton("Изменить расписание уроков"))
    delete_schedule = (types.KeyboardButton("Удалить текущее расписание уроков"))
    markup.add(change_schedule, delete_schedule)
    printy(message.chat.id, "Настройка расписание уроков:", reply_markup=markup)

def settings_time_schedule(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    change_time_schedule = (types.KeyboardButton("Изменить текущее время проведения уроков"))
    delete_time_schedule = (types.KeyboardButton("Удалить текущее время уроков"))
    markup.add(change_time_schedule, delete_time_schedule)
    printy(message.chat.id, "Настройка времени проведения уроков:", reply_markup=markup)

def information(message):
    printy(message.chat.id, f"Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}! \nДанный бот создан для рассылки расписания уроков.")
    printy(message.chat.id, "Создатель бота: https://t.me/Mr_GoldSky")


def change_time_schedule_one(message):
    printy(message.chat.id, ("Введите максимальное кол-во уроков в день"))
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, take_answer_one)

def take_answer_one(message):
    how_many_lessons = message.text
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, change_time_schedule_two)

def change_time_schedule_two(message):
    printy(message.chat.id, ("Введите длительность урока"))
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, take_answer_two)

def take_answer_two(message):
    time_lesson = message.text
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, change_time_schedule_three)

def change_time_schedule_three(message):
    printy(message.chat.id, ("Введите длительность перемены"))
    time_break = message.text
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, change_time_schedule_four)

def change_time_schedule_four(message):
    for j in range(1, how_many_lessons + 1):
        printy(message.chat.id, f"Введите начало вашего {j} урока:")
        pass

    for j in range(1, how_many_lessons + 1):
        printy(message.chat.id, f"Введите конец вашего {j} урока:")
        pass

@bot.message_handler()
def get_user_text(message):
    if message.text == "Информация о боте":
        information(message)
    elif message.text == "Настройка расписание уроков":
        settings_schedule(message)
    elif message.text == "Настройка времени проведения уроков":
        settings_time_schedule(message)
    elif message.text == "Изменить текущее время проведения уроков":
        change_time_schedule_one(message)
    else:
        printy(message.chat.id, "Нет такой команды")

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Гугли метод register_next_step_handler

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py

Comment: @СергейШашко Получается мне нужно сделать множество функций? К примеру, если уроков 7, то нужно и 7 функций и что-бы они все ссылались друг на друга по порядку?

Comment: @ProgerOffline Получается мне нужно сделать множество функций? К примеру, если уроков 7, то нужно и 7 функций и что-бы они все ссылались друг на друга по порядку?

Comment: Можете сразу закидывать все целиком, через какой-то разделитель что потом можно разделить текст, или есть не нужно тогда просто целиком закидывайте.